# Can C++17's "template argument deduction" for class templates deduce local types?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++17, template-argument-deduction

[P0091R3 *("Template argument deduction for class templates")*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html) was recently added to [`gcc` trunk](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z) and can be tested on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox).

Something I had in mind was the possibility of using it to implement a 
*"scope guard"* in very few lines of code:

```
scope_guard _([]{ cout << "hi!\n" });
```

---

I tried [implementing it on wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eH1IQPERTyXLW9zk)...

```
template <typename TF>
struct scope_guard : TF
{
    scope_guard(TF f) : TF{f} { }
    ~scope_guard() { (*this)(); }
};

int main() 
{
    scope_guard _{[]{}};
}
```

...but compilation failed with the following error:

```
prog.cc:6:5: error: 'scope_guard(TF)-> scope_guard<TF> [with TF = main()::<lambda()>]', declared using local type 'main()::<lambda()>', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
     scope_guard(TF f) : TF{std::move(f)} { }
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

I then tried [using a non-lambda local type](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jpnaNmjtoHZVQ05f), and got the same error.

```
int main() 
{
    struct K { void operator()() {} };
    scope_guard _{K{}};
}
```

---

Afterwards, [I tried a non-local type](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Awwan8ZFhlLCC1ug), and it worked as expected.

```
struct K { void operator()() {} };

int main() 
{
    scope_guard _{K{}};
}
```

---

**Is this featured designed in such a way that prevents local types from being deduced?**

Or **is this a defect in `gcc`'s current implementation of the feature?**

Comment: Looks like you already found and commented on the bug report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in the current implementation: [77890](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77890) (<s>NEW implies validity, as opposed to UNCONFIRMED</s> fixed in 7.0). Being able to deduce a lambda was one of the motivating examples of the original paper, so would be quite awkward if it didn't work:

> ```
> // Virtually impossible to pass a lambda to a template class' constructor without declaring the lambda
> for_each(vi2.begin(), vi2.end(), Foo<???>([&](int i) { ...}));
> ```

> ```
> for_each(vi.begin(), vi.end(), Foo([&](int i) { ...})); // Now easy instead of virtually impossible
> ```

We can create a really basic example:

```
template <typename TF>
struct scope_guard
{
    scope_guard(TF ) { }
};

int main()
{
    scope_guard _([]{});
}
```

This should perform overload resolution on the synthesized function set consisting of the functions:

```
template <class TF> scope_guard<TF> synthesized(TF );
template <class TF> scope_guard<TF> synthesized(scope_guard<TF> const& );
template <class TF> scope_guard<TF> synthesized(scope_guard<TF>&& );
```

which should pick the first overload and use that return type as the type of `_`, with `TF` being type of the lambda. This should all work.

Comment: [The original snippet now compiles on **wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DOEBWFOU6YyKLPYe).